# How to override vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php and vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php?

Tags: magento2, overrides, zend-framework

I created a custom module and to try to override `vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php`

but

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql" type="Test\MySQLCluster\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql" />
```

does not work for `vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`

And for `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php` I don`t know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A normal preference won't work indeed, but you can copy it to the `lib` directory. It's not a very clean way of working but in this case required.

`lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`

Comment: Hi, can you please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300048/magento2-3-2-could-not-load-sales-channels-for-stock