# Magento2.3.2:Website is not opening & Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist

Tags: magento2.3.2, sales, aws, exception-error

I am working on Magento2.3.2 in the AWS server with Lightsail Instance with the website URL **https://13.235.236.199/**.

Suddenly the website is not opening and it is showing the error sometimes like

**Could not load Sales Channels for Stock**

I thought one of the installed extension is causing the error. So, I disabled that extension and ran the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Still no improvement.

Sometimes, I am getting the error instead of the above error,

**Something happening while loading the website. Please check exception log for details**

The error in exception.log is as follows:

> [2020-01-02 09:36:42] main.CRITICAL: Class
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist
>   {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist at
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"}
>   []

**New Update:**

As per the existed answers, I recompiled the code, deployed the static content and cleared the cache.

Now, I got a new issue like the following:

> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---6da_COMPILED_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 691

**After successful working the website, again get new error in log:**

> {"0":"Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---c40_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 691","1":"#1 file_put_contents('/opt/bitnami/app...',
>   'c40_THEME_BY_ID_...', 10) called at
>   [vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php:691]\n#2
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_File->_updateIdsTags(array('c40_THEME_BY_ID_...'),
>   array('c40_MAGE'), 'merge') called at
>   [vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php:203]\n#3
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_File->save('{\"theme_id\":\"4\",...',
>   'c40_THEME_BY_ID_...', array('c40_MAGE'), NULL) called at
>   [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Core.php:390]\n#4
>   Zend_Cache_Core->save('{\"theme_id\":\"4\",...',
>   'c40_THEME_BY_ID_...', array('c40_MAGE'), NULL, 8) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Core.php:74]\n#5
>   Magento\Framework\Cache\Core->save('{\"theme_id\":\"4\",...',
>   'THEME-BY-ID-4', array('c40_MAGE'), NULL) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Adapter/Zend.php:63]\n#6
>   Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Adapter\Zend->save('{\"theme_id\":\"4\",...',
>   'theme-by-id-4', array('MAGE'), NULL) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php:75]\n#7
>   Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('{\"theme_id\":\"4\",...',
>   'theme-by-id-4', array('MAGE'), NULL) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/TagScope.php:52]\n#8
>   Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope->save('{\"theme_id\":\"4\",...',
>   'theme-by-id-4', array('MAGE'), NULL) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php:75]\n#9
>   Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('{\"theme_id\":\"4\",...',
>   'theme-by-id-4', array(), NULL) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache.php:73]\n#10
>   Magento\Framework\App\Cache->save('{\"theme_id\":\"4\",...',
>   'theme-by-id-4', array(), NULL) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Proxy.php:81]\n#11
>   Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Proxy->save('{\"theme_id\":\"4\",...',
>   'theme-by-id-4') called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/ThemeProvider.php:166]\n#12
>   Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\ThemeProvider->saveThemeToCache(&Magento\Theme\Model\Theme#0000000002ffcfb7000000003cdd0d2d#,
>   'theme-by-id-4') called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/ThemeProvider.php:132]\n#13
>   Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\ThemeProvider->getThemeById(4) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/FlyweightFactory.php:102]\n#14
>   Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\FlyweightFactory->_loadById(4)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/FlyweightFactory.php:64]\n#15
>   Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\FlyweightFactory->create(4,
>   'frontend') called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/View/Design.php:148]\n#16
>   Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design->setDesignTheme(4) called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/View/Design.php:212]\n#17
>   Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design->setDefaultDesignTheme() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php:261]\n#18
>   Magento\Framework\App\Area->_initDesign() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php:219]\n#19
>   Magento\Framework\App\Area->_loadPart('design') called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php:143]\n#20
>   Magento\Framework\App\Area->load('design') called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/DesignLoader.php:54]\n#21
>   Magento\Framework\View\DesignLoader->load() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php:48]\n#22
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->beforeDispatch(&Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor#0000000002ffcfd3000000003cdd0d2d#,
>   &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:121]\n#23
>   Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#24
>   Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#),
>   array(array('designLoader', 'customerNotifica...',
>   'catalog_app_acti...', 'tax-app-action-d...', 'weee-app-action-...',
>   'storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'))) called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:26]\n#25
>   Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]\n#26
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#,
>   &Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor#0000000002ffcfd3000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]\n#27
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#28
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#))
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#29
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]\n#30 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#0000000002ffcd18000000003cdd0d2d#,
>   &Closure#0000000002ffccf5000000003cdd0d2d#,
>   &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#31
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]\n#32
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#0000000002ffcd18000000003cdd0d2d#,
>   &Closure#0000000002ffccf5000000003cdd0d2d#,
>   &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#33
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#34
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#),
>   NULL) called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]\n#35
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000002ffca53000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]\n#36
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#37
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000002ffcaad000000003cdd0d2d#)
>   called at
>   [index.php:39]\n</pre>","url":"/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Comment: I will look the question shortly

Comment: remove generated and check again

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara please disable webkul module and try again, i think issue because of webkul module

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, i have disabled all existing 7 webkul modules and ran the setup:upgrade, indexer and cache commands also. still no change, its loading only

Comment: try to give open permission to var/ pub/ generated/

Comment: Need to recreate Interceptor run this command

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: can you share me this file 1005215466950.log from var/reports/

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel, i just edite the description

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara see my updated answer below, this should fix your problem
By the way: the problems you describe are typical if you run `bin/magento` as root - always remember to run the command as your magento file owner (`mage` or whatever the name of the user might be)

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara as per log, I think you miscode for c40_THEME_BY_ID. because that is not not getting  c40_THEME_BY_ID  so. please try to figure out it.

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara, Run all command using "sudo"

Comment: @SanjayGohil acutally that's not a good idea! running everything as root messes up your permissions, and can be dangerous!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Things you can try:

remove the generated code directory (again):

```
rm generated/code -rf
```

upgrade your modules and re-compile:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

if there are any errors during compile, you found the reason for your problem - fix these errors first, and redo all the steps mentioned here.

and if you're in *production* mode (check the output of `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`)

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and finally clean your cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

#### Update regarding the second warning/error:

You need to get your file permissions right, the magento Documentation is a good place to read up on the topic: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

To summarize, this is what you need to do (assuming you have a user, let's say `mage` and a group, let's say `www-data` on your system)

Fix the file ownership:

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/
chown -R mage:www-data *
```

Fix the file permissions:

```
find var generated pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + &&
find var generated pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
```

And maybe try manually deleting your cache directory:

```
rm -rf var/cache
```

If this doesn't help, please post the output of `ls -al` in your magento root directory (which is /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/).

Answer (score 6):

**Magento2 Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist**

This issue is generate when you have make changes in your construction file and it's Factory class is not update in **generated** folder

For that you need remove generated folder from your magento root

```
rm -rf generated/*
```

After remove generated now compile the site

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

After successful compilation now deploy the content

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

now check your issue is resolved... Please accept answer if it's resolved.

Answer (score 1):

After 3-4 days of searching for the issue on the internet, I found the answer as the follows:

**Add the following configuration to your app/etc/env.php file right before the last line of ];**

```
  'cache' =>
  array (
    'frontend' =>
    array (
      'default' =>
      array (
        'backend_options' =>
        array (
          'hashed_directory_umask' => NULL,
          'directory_mode' => NULL,
          'file_mode' => NULL,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Afterwards, be sure to have the correct permissions and SETGID bit assigned to the var and var/page_cache and var/cache directories, as described in the devdocs. You can set to drwxrwsr-x. Next, run the following commands as your magento file-system user:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Source:** https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10588

Answer (score 1):

Interceptor does not exist issue arises when changing made in constructor parameters and the Factory classes is not generated anyhow.

For that you need remove generated folder from your magento root

```
rm -rf generated/*
```

After remove generated run following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

after upgrading databases and created dynamic classes in generated folder run

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

After successful compilation now deploy the content

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

In developer and default mode static content deploy not neede for that you have to deploy static content forcefully -f

now check issue has been resolved. Please accept answer if it's resolved.